# How to run multiple webdrivers at same time?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

why it stops after getting url by  first driver? how can i fix it? i need connect multiple webdrivers at same time

```
from selenium import webdriver
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

num = 2

process = [None] * num

def get(id, port):
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", f"127.0.0.1:{port}")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    print(port)
    driver.get(f"https://www.google.com?id={id}")
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.quit()  # Use quit() instead of close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    workers = [924, 923]

    for i in range(num):
        port = workers[i]
        process[i] = Process(target=get, args=(i, port))
        process[i].start()

    for i in range(num):
        process[i].join()
```

Comment: doesn't seem like you should be joining.  Why join?  Also not sure why you are setting debuggerAddress.  That's usually for attaching to a browser already launched by an IDE.

Comment: Also,  why use multiprocessing for I/O tasks ?

Comment: @D.L I need to perform a simultaneous action in browsers under different profiles, it is very important that this happens simultaneously

Comment: @pcalkins I tried with creating browsers and not connecting them via debugeradress, and it was the same, they just blocked

Comment: @trcmzng,  the actions are much more likely to be simultaneous if `threading` or `asyncio` is used.

Comment: solved, just use playwright